# Counting column values based on values in other columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, count, pandas-groupby

I am trying to count how many 0 and 1 a student got with pandas in python. For example, I have the following data frame.

```
+----------------------------------+--------+
|             Students             | Grades |  
+----------------------------------+--------+
| Student1                         |      0 |
| Student1                         |      1 |
| Student1                         |      2 |
| Student2                         |      3 |
| Student2                         |      5 |
| Student2                         |      0 |
| Student3                         |      3 |
| Student3                         |      4 |
| Student3                         |      5 |
+----------------------------------+--------+
```

As you can see student1 got one grade 0 and one grade 1 totally he got 2. Student2 got only 1 and student3 got 0 (no grade 1 and 0) . I could not figure out how to do it. does anyone know the code to count?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Welcome to SO; if the answer resolved your issue, kindly accept it - see [`What should I do when someone answers my question?`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try creating a boolean column checking if `Grades` are in `[0,1]` , then group on `Students` and take sum.

```
out = (df['Grades'].isin([0,1]).groupby(df['Students']).sum()
                     .astype(int).reset_index(name='Counts'))
```

---

```
   Students  Counts
0  Student1       2
1  Student2       1
2  Student3       0
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that would solve my problem. Do you know how to merge students in single entry and add counts column in the dataframe as you show in your example?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
>>> df.groupby('Students').agg(lambda x:sum(x.lt(2))).Grades.reset_index(name='Count')
   Students  Counts
0  Student1       2
1  Student2       1
2  Student3       0
```

References:

1. [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)
2. [`series.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html)
3. [`series.lt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.lt.html)
4. [`df.groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.1/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html)

Comment: Thank you so much, that would solve my problem. Do you know how to merge students in single entry and add counts column in the dataframe as you show in your example?